# .slice() is not a function although called on string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to figure out some collision, but the compiler keeps showing the error that .slice() is not a function. Here is the code:

```
var topPos1 = $('#player').css("top");
var rightPos1 = $('#player').css("right");
var topPos2 = $('#player').css("top");
var rightPos2 = $('#player').css("right");
var pos = topPos1.indexOf('px');
topPos1 = parseInt(topPos1.slice(0,pos));
```

My jQuery is loaded.

Comment: why are you using `topPos1 = parseInt(topPos1.slice(0,pos));`. This makes no sense..

Comment: It's not so absurd, you change the value of the variable using an operation on itself.

Comment: Is topPos1 != undefined ?

Comment: It seems like you want to do substring operation to get value of pixels, there is nothing about jQuery's slice(). And answering exact question - you call the function not for jQuery object, but for a String and slice() is not defined for a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `topPos1` return nothing, if the `$('#player')` has no css value for `top`, assigning it to a value will result `null` or `NaN`.

You should use log the values to see if the result are correct.

Comment: If `topPos1` is a string, you don't need to slice it, : `parseInt("150px") = 150`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly slice a number, you can convert it into string then `slice` after

like this:

```
topPos1 = parseInt(topPos1.toString().slice(0,pos));
```

Comment: `$('#player').css("top");` would return a string - something like '100px', or 'auto' if nothing is set.

Comment: topPos1 is a string ending with 'px' that's why I have to slice it, I want to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.replace('px', '')` - it will save you one function call